# morbo slows down and hangs after a while

Tags: macos, perl, mojolicious

When developing an app, I have running morbo for several hours to check the impacts of my changes - so far, I think this is exactly what morbo has been developed for.

But after a while (aprox. 2 hours) the app starts to get unresponsive and finally  hangs. If that happens I can **not** stop morbo anymore with `Ctrl+C`. The only way is to kill the two morbo-processes (`ps -ax | grep morbo`, `kill -9 <id1> <id2>`. Unfortunately that does not cure the system in an sustainable way - after a few minutes the app hangs again. The only way is to restart the whole machine, which is quiet uncommon for a UNIX based OS.

System: OS X, Perl v5.12.3 darwin-2level, Mojolicious (5.44, Tiger Face)

Any idea?

Comment: In the meantime I have at least an guess, what the cause of that slow-down *could* be: I had two terminal-windows open. One for starting morbo and the other for committing to git. So it happened that I added, committed, tagged to the repository while morbo was still running. Is it possible that this confuses morbo?